# About mouse guard

Tags: mouse-guard

Questions, firstly, what does +1s mean? I still do not understand how weapons benefit the player using them. Secondly, wouldn't all players be better off with a low Nature score? what are the benefits of a high nature score? And finally, how can we homebrew other creatures like hares and hawks to be playable critters? Also, how can we add magic? I just added Arcana to either replace one starting skill or it can be learned.

Comment: Please split up your question into three seperate questions :)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour]. This site provides rated answers to specific questions about role-playing games, so questions should be split up as much as is practical in order to make it possible for there to be one best answer, instead of three different competing answers that each answer different parts of the question the best. You can edit this question down to one and then ask two more.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you specified first or second edition Mouse Guard.

Comment: It's been about six weeks, so I've broken this question up into its four component parts, [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/188312/), [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/188314), [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/188316), and [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/188318).